# How can I add new dimensions to a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm starting off with a numpy array of an image.

```
In[1]:img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
```

The shape is what you might expect for a 640x480 RGB image.

```
In[2]:img.shape
Out[2]: (480, 640, 3)
```

However, this image that I have is a frame of a video, which is 100 frames long. Ideally, I would like to have a single array that contains all the data from this video such that `img.shape` returns `(480, 640, 3, 100)`.

What is the best way to add the next frame -- that is, the next set of image data, another 480 x 640 x 3 array -- to my initial array?

Answer (score 199):

A dimension can be added to a numpy array as follows:

```
image = image[..., np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Currently, `numpy.newaxis` is defined to be `None` (in file `numeric.py`), so equivalently you could use `image = image[..., None].

Comment: Don't use `None`. Use `np.newaxis` because explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: How can that be? `None` does not imply anything. It is explicit. It is `None`. Stated clearly.`None` **is** a _thing_ in python. There is no doubt. `None` is the last detail, you cannot go deeper. On the other hand, `numpy.newaxis` implies `None`. It is, essentially, `None`. It is `None`. But is `None` implicitly. It is `None` though not directly expressed as `None`. **Explicit** _stated clearly and in detail, leaving no room for confusion or doubt._ **Implicit** _suggested though not directly expressed._ I must add, that, from an API perspective, it is safer to use `numpy.newaxis`.

Comment: Guess here, being explicit refers to the "coder intent" rather than to the syntactical/semantical clarity.

Comment: JoshAdel's answer should be selected as the right answer in this case and needs more votes. His point is significant in that the OP is looking to add to the higher dimensioned nparray as he goes. ndarray's cannot be increased in size once created, a copy must be made. This answer will only make the shape (480, 640, 3, 1) and every time you add a new frame you will be making another copy. Not good.

Comment: Since the title asks about adding (multiple) dimension**s**, I would like to add a way to add `n` dimensions:
`a[(..., *([np.newaxis] * n))]`. The parentheses constructing a `tuple` are necessary to unpack the `list` of `n` times `np.newaxis`

Comment: @PedroRodrigues: if a software developer gives you something explicit like `numpy.newaxis`, then just because it _happens_ to be something basic **today**, there's no guarantee that it'll be the **same** thing in the next code release.  However, there is a fairly strong implied contract that whatever `numpy.newaxis` is in the next release, it'll still behave the same.

Answer (score 108):

Alternatively to

```
image = image[..., np.newaxis]
```

in [@dbliss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755697/1534017), you can also use [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) like

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, <your desired dimension>)
```

For example (taken from the link above):

```
x = np.array([1, 2])

print(x.shape)  # prints (2,)
```

Then

```
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

yields

```
array([[1, 2]])
```

and

```
y.shape
```

gives

```
(1, 2)
```

Comment: how to add values in the new dimention? if i do `y[1,0]` it gives index out of bounds error. `y[0,1]` is accessible

Comment: @weima: Not fully sure what you are after. What is your desired output?

Comment: Where is the value of "your desired dimension" go? I can see only the value 1

Answer (score 33):

You could just create an array of the correct size up-front and fill it:

```
frames = np.empty((480, 640, 3, 100))

for k in xrange(nframes):
    frames[:,:,:,k] = cv2.imread('frame_{}.jpg'.format(k))
```

if the frames were individual jpg file that were named in some particular way (in the example, frame_0.jpg, frame_1.jpg, etc).

Just a note, you might consider using a `(nframes, 480,640,3)` shaped array, instead.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. if you use the concatenation you will need to move the array in memory every time you add to it. for 100 frames that should not matter at all, but if you want to go to larger videos. BTW, I would have used the number of frames as the first dimension so have a (100,480,640,3) array that way you can access individual frames (what is usually want you will want to look at, right?) easier (F[1] instead of F[:,:,:,1]). Of course performance wise it should not matter at all.

Comment: I agree with JoshAdel and Magellan88, the other answers are very inefficient memory wise and processing time-- ndarrays cannot be increased in size once created, so a copy will always be made if you think you are appending to it.

Answer (score 27):

Pythonic

`X = X[:, :, None]`

which is equivalent to

`X = X[:, :, numpy.newaxis]` and
`X = numpy.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)`

But as you are explicitly asking about stacking images,
I would recommend going for stacking the `list` of images `np.stack([X1, X2, X3])` that you may have collected in a loop.

If you do not like the order of the dimensions you can rearrange with `np.transpose()`

Answer (score 14):

```
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=-1)
```

or

```
a = a[:, np.newaxis]
```

or

```
a = a.reshape(a.shape + (1,))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `np.concatenate()` use the `axis` parameter to specify the dimension that should be concatenated. If the arrays being concatenated do not have this dimension, you can use `np.newaxis` to indicate where the new dimension should be added:

```
import numpy as np
movie = np.concatenate((img1[:,np.newaxis], img2[:,np.newaxis]), axis=3)
```

If you are reading from many files:

```
import glob
movie = np.concatenate([cv2.imread(p)[:,np.newaxis] for p in glob.glob('*.jpg')], axis=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider Approach 1 with reshape method and Approach 2 with np.newaxis method that produce the same outcome:

```
#Lets suppose, we have:
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('I. x',x)

xNpArr = np.array(x)
print('II. xNpArr',xNpArr)
print('III. xNpArr', xNpArr.shape)

xNpArr_3x3 = xNpArr.reshape((3,3))
print('IV. xNpArr_3x3.shape', xNpArr_3x3.shape)
print('V. xNpArr_3x3', xNpArr_3x3)

#Approach 1 with reshape method
xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1 = xNpArr_3x3.reshape((1,3,3,1))
print('VI. xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1.shape', xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1.shape)
print('VII. xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1', xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1)

#Approach 2 with np.newaxis method
xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1 = xNpArr_3x3[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis]
print('VIII. xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1.shape', xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1.shape)
print('IX. xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1', xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1)
```

We have as outcome:

```
I. x [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

II. xNpArr [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

III. xNpArr (9,)

IV. xNpArr_3x3.shape (3, 3)

V. xNpArr_3x3 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

VI. xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1.shape (1, 3, 3, 1)

VII. xNpArrRs_1x3x3x1 [[[[1]
   [2]
   [3]]

  [[4]
   [5]
   [6]]

  [[7]
   [8]
   [9]]]]

VIII. xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1.shape (1, 3, 3, 1)

IX. xNpArrNa_1x3x3x1 [[[[1]
   [2]
   [3]]

  [[4]
   [5]
   [6]]

  [[7]
   [8]
   [9]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no structure in numpy that allows you to append more data later.

Instead, numpy puts all of your data into a contiguous chunk of numbers (basically; a C array), and any resize requires allocating a new chunk of memory to hold it. Numpy's speed comes from being able to keep all the data in a numpy array in the same chunk of memory; e.g. mathematical operations can be [parallelized for speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) and you get less [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss).

So you will have two kinds of solutions:

1. Pre-allocate the memory for the numpy array and fill in the values, like in JoshAdel's answer, or
2. Keep your data in a normal python list until it's actually needed to put them all together (see below)

---

```
images = []
for i in range(100):
    new_image = # pull image from somewhere
    images.append(new_image)
images = np.stack(images, axis=3)
```

---

Note that there is no need to expand the dimensions of the individual image arrays first, nor do you need to know how many images you expect ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stack with the axis parameter:

```
img.shape  # h,w,3
imgs = np.stack([img1,img2,img3,img4], axis=-1)   # -1 = new axis is last
imgs.shape #  h,w,3,nimages
```

For example: to convert grayscale to color:

```
>>> d = np.zeros((5,4), dtype=int)  # 5x4
>>> d[2,3] = 1

>>> d3.shape
Out[30]: (5, 4, 3)

>>> d3 = np.stack([d,d,d], axis=-2)  # 5x4x3   -1=as last axis
>>> d3[2,3]
Out[32]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed this approach:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

ls = []

for image in image_paths:
    ls.append(cv2.imread('test.jpg'))

img_np = np.array(ls) # shape (100, 480, 640, 3)
img_np = np.rollaxis(img_np, 0, 4) # shape (480, 640, 3, 100).
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
image = image[..., None]
```

Comment: where is the reference to this, please?

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you add axis anywhere you want**

```
    import numpy as np
    signal = np.array([[0.3394572666491664, 0.3089068053925853, 0.3516359279582483], [0.33932706934615525, 0.3094755563319447, 0.3511973743219001], [0.3394407172182317, 0.30889042266755573, 0.35166886011421256], [0.3394407172182317, 0.30889042266755573, 0.35166886011421256]])
    
    print(signal.shape)
#(4,3)
    print(signal[...,np.newaxis].shape)  or  signal[...:none]
#(4, 3, 1) 
    print(signal[:, np.newaxis, :].shape)  or signal[:,none, :]

#(4, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is three-way for adding new dimensions to ndarray .

**first:** using "np.newaxis" (something like @dbliss answer)

- np.newaxis is just given an alias to None for making it easier to
  understand. If you replace np.newaxis with None, it works the same
  way. but it's better to use np.newaxis for being more explicit.

```py
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.array([2, 3])
new_arr = my_arr[..., np.newaxis]

print("old shape", my_arr.shape)
print("new shape", new_arr.shape)

>>> old shape (2,)
>>> new shape (2, 1)
```

**second:** using "np.expand_dims()"

- Specify the original ndarray in the first argument and the position
  to add the dimension in the second argument axis.

```py
my_arr = np.array([2, 3])
new_arr = np.expand_dims(my_arr, -1)

print("old shape", my_arr.shape)
print("new shape", new_arr.shape)

>>> old shape (2,)
>>> new shape (2, 1)
```

**third:** using "reshape()"

```py
my_arr = np.array([2, 3])
new_arr = my_arr.reshape(*my_arr.shape, 1)

print("old shape", my_arr.shape)
print("new shape", new_arr.shape)

>>> old shape (2,)
>>> new shape (2, 1)
```