# How to create matrix with vector multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a 2x2 array from a size 2 vector `x` by doing matrix multiplication like `x * x^T`:

```
>>> x = np.array([2, 2])
>>> x
array([2, 2])
>>> np.matmul(x,x.T)
8
```

As you can see, this fails. I came up with this solution:

```
>>> m = np.matrix(x)
>>> m
matrix([[2, 2]])
>>> m.T
matrix([[2],
        [2]])
>>> np.matmul(m.T, m)
matrix([[4, 4],
        [4, 4]])
```

Which achieves what I want. But is there a better way to do this, preferrably without resorting to using `np.matrix`?

EDIT: Creating a 2x1 vector is not an option because of the context outside the question.

Comment: `np.outer(x, x)`?

Comment: You don't really need to use `matrix`, but you need to have a shape that gives you the result shape you want. `x = np.array([[2, 2]])` gives you a shape of `(1, 2)` which you can multiply with `np.matmul(x.T,x)`

Comment: beware that you do not really have a "2x1 vector" here, but a 1D vector as `x.shape` returns `(2,)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
np.outer(x, x)
# array([[4, 4],
#        [4, 4]])
```

---

Alternatively, [increase `x`'s dimension by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/add-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array) before calling `np.matmul`:

```
x = x[:, None]  # x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
x.shape
# (2, 1)

x @ x.T  # (2,1) . (1,2) => (2,2)
# array([[4, 4],
#        [4, 4]])
```

Comment: I think the use of `reshape` would be much clearer to increase x's dimension than what you suggest: `x.reshape(1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you reshaped `x`, you can use the `@` operator to do the multiplication:

```
x = np.array([2, 2])
Xprime = x.reshape(len(x), 1)
print(Xprime @ Xprime.T)
#[[4 4]
# [4 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.array([2, 2])` doesn't create a 2x1 vector, it creates a 2 vector. If you want a 2x1 matrix, you need  `np.array([[2], [2]])`. Or you can create a 1x2 matrix with  `np.array([[2, 2]])` and then do `np.matmul(x.T,x)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a 2x1 vector here, but a 1D vector. You can see that with:

```
> x.shape
(2,)
```

To actually create a 2x1 vector, add bracets:

```
> x = np.array([[2, 2]])
> x.shape
(1,2)
```

And now you have what you want with:

```
> np.matmul(x.T,x)
array([[4, 4],
       [4, 4]])
```

or `x.T@x` in Python3.