# how to convert an array of dimension three to five in keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, reshape

I have an array of shape `(?, ?, 128)` and I want to convert it to `(?, ?, 128,1,1)`.

I tried to search it but I did not find any good thing or maybe I did not use correct words for finding what I am looking for.
is there any efficient way I can do that?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/add-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array) is the most relevant thing I found which is not the same as the thing I want.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This is easy to do with `numpy` arrays - either with `reshape` on `np.newaxis`.  I don't know what `keras` allows.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you please give the equivalent in Numpy?

Comment: @user2699 but adding newaxis alone create a dimension with None. also, here ? is creating a problem. I mean I do not know the correct dimension of my first two axis so I want to keep it as it is.

Comment: `arr[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`, `arr.reshape(arr.shape + (1,1))`.  Here is use `tuple` join to create a new shape.  The '?' keras dimensions are a big unknown.  Surely keras documentation has something about reshaping?

Comment: @sariii, No, the first answer given in the duplicate addresses that.  The number of dimensions are changed, but the shape of the original dimensions are kept.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you so much. I could not find in keras doc but I will look into it again. but it won't give me my desired output. actually it created something like(?,? 128,1,1,1).

Comment: @user2699 I just did not include link here and already met that link. I would prefer the equivalent code in keras. I will update the subject then

Comment: Then why on earth did you include a question about php as the "most relevant link", tag the question with numpy, and include numpy in the title?

Comment: @user2699 You are correct in this, I will update sorry for that.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you it is now working in numpy I will try to find equivalent way in Keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Numpy, you can do `reshape`

```
a = np.random.rand(2, 3, 128)
b = a.reshape(a.shape + (1, 1))
```

With [Keras](https://keras.io/backend/#expand_dims), you can do `keras.backend.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)` to add a 1-sized dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I want to do that in keras

Comment: The [official Keras document](https://keras.io/backend/#expand_dims) says `keras.backend.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)` "adds a 1-sized dimension at index axis".

Comment: can you please update your answer so I can accept that?

Comment: Updated the answer!