# How can I append a single row dimension to an ndarray shape?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a model that takes in an ndArray of a shape like (10,32,32,1) 
for 10 32x32 images - but using PIL and numpy to load and split the images

```
            imgArray = np.array(img,dtype="float32")
            img.verify()


        split = np.split(imgArray, 10, axis=1)
```

I end up with a shape of (10,32,32).

How can I add a single row dimension to make this (10,32,32,1)?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array).  You can use something like: `y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=3)`

Comment: Also, `np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)` or `x.reshape(x.shape + (1,))`