# Add dimension to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If I have a `numpy` array of dimensions like this

`[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]`

is there a simple way to modify it so the dimensions are like  this?

`[[[1,2,3]],[[2,3,4]],[[3,4,5]]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new dimensions to a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply reshape it:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
a.reshape(3,1,3)
```

also you can make it dynamic:

```
row = a.shape[0]
col = a.shape[1]
a.reshape(row, 1, col)
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.expand_dims() for expanding array dimensions. See the official docs for details: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
>>> x[:,None,:]

array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5]]])
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
>>> x[:, np.newaxis, :]

array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5]]])
```

Which again is almost equivalent to,

```
>>> np.expand_dims(x, 1)

array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5]]])
```