# How to reshape an array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

How can we reshape an array in python, For example

`original_array = [1,2,3,4]`

**and what I want after reshaping is this,**

`[[1,2,3,4]]`

I reshaped the array using this code,

```
original = np.asarray(original)
original = original.reshape(original.shape[0], 1)
```

but what I get is something like this,

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `reshaped_array = [patient_data]` try this.

Comment: Seems valid to me or: patient_data = [original_array]. Please edit your question if this does not help you. It is also somewhat unclear to me if the question is resolved by this.

Comment: Is `original_array` a list or a `numpy` array? Looks like a list but there's a `numpy` tag

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question

Comment: The original shape is (4,).  You want (1,4), you get (4,1).  See the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new dimensions to a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 6):

You just need to have the arguments of `.reshape()` in different order:

```
patient_data = patient_data.reshape(1, patient_data.shape[0])
```

or, possibly better:

```
patient_data = patient_data.reshape(1, -1)
```

---

There are a couple of other methods to get to this, e.g.:

```
patient_data = patient_data[None, :]
```

```
patient_data = patient_data[None, ...]
```

```
patient_data = patient_data[np.newaxis, :]
```

```
patient_data = patient_data[np.newaxis, ...]
```

```
patient_data = np.expand_dims(patient_data, 0)
```

---

Probably the chapter on [Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in NumPy's documentation is a good read for you.

Comment: Sorry i edited my question will the above will be applicable?

Comment: Wow this worked!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

If `original_array` is a `numpy` array and not a list, you can use `expand_dims` from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
original_array = np.array([1,2,3,4])

np.expand_dims(original_array,axis=0)
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: This worked !! Thank you very much !!!!1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand_dims` from `numpy` then:

```
import numpy
original_array = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
numpy.expand_dims(original_array, axis=0)
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```