# Unable to understand why tensorflow cannot convert numpy array to tensor

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently looking to build a CNN-LSTM hybrid model to process Skin cancer images. The images have been resized to (270, 300, 3) (width, height, channels) using the cv2.resize function. This is how I've split the data and created the model.

```py
true_labels = np.asarray(test_sample_light_dark['malignant_cancer'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sample_light_dark_image_data, true_labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)

valid_X_train, valid_X_test, valid_y_train, valid_y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 4)
# Model Creation
input_shape = (1, 270, 300, 3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu')))
#model_mix_shoulder.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu')))
#model_mix_shoulder.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(56,(3,3),activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))

#model_mix_shoulder.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu')))
#model_mix_shoulder.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

#RNN
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
#model.add(activation('sigmoid'))

#model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 25,validation_data = (valid_X_train, valid_y_train), shuffle=True, batch_size=32)
```

The error that I'm getting is as follows:

````
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).```

I've double checked that the output of each training dataset sample is a numpy.ndarray of shape (270,300,3) which matches the shape of the input to my CNN. And, I've also checked that I'm able to convert the internal numpy array of the train dataset into a tensor. Where exactly am I going wrong?

I don't have a lot of experience with deep learning in general.

I've tried variaous operations such as reshaping but even they don't work as I got an error saying that the `X_train` data with shape (1600,) cannot be reshaped into (270,300,3).
````

Comment: Most commonly the array (one of `valid_X_train, valid_y_train`) is not a neat n-d numeric dtype array. It may be object dtype, or if a list, contain arrays that differ in shape.  For a start check the shape and dtype of those arguments.

Comment: First off, change your `input_shape` to `(270,300,3)`. The first dimension is the `batch_size` which will be automatically inferred by keras when you pass `batch_size` in `model.fit()`

Comment: The current shapes for X_Train, X_test, valid_X_train, valid_X_test is 

(1600,) (400,) (280,) (120,).  The internal shape of a single row in the above split is (270,300,3) and their type is uint8.

Comment: @Raktim, I tried changing the input shape as you suggested but I started getting other errors related to dimensions after that change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399263/incompatible-inputs-of-layers-ndim-4-found-ndim-3

Comment: Is it right for `valid_X_train` to be 1d, (400,)?  What's the dtype?  Why not 4d? (batch, hight, width,channels)?

Comment: @hpaulj, after the train test split, should I reshape the data into (batch, height, width and channels)?

Comment: Do all the reshaping before splitting.  Make sure the number of channels is consistent as well..

Comment: Okay. But how do i solve the current error @hpaulj?

Comment: You have the data, I don't.  I have no idea of what it is, how you load it, how you reshape it, etc.

Comment: @hpaulj, can we continue this conversation in a chat?

Comment: I don't have further hints to add.  I know nothing about your data.