# Seperate each item in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the list of two arrays which was the result of a loop and I am trying to do the following:

From this:

```
import numpy as np
data=[np.array(['one','two','three']),np.array(['four','five','six'])]
data
```

which gives

```
[array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='<U5'),
 array(['four', 'five', 'six'], dtype='<U4')]
```

to this expected result:

```
[array([['one'],
        ['two'],
        ['three']], dtype='<U5'),
 array([['four'],
        ['five'],
        ['six']], dtype='<U4')]
```

I have tried np.split but didn't do the expected.

Comment: you mean take the transpose? like `[a.T for a in data]` ?

Comment: No, this does not put each word in a separate list.See the expected result.

Comment: yes my bad, transpose doesn't do what I thought it did for 1d arrays,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new dimensions to a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: You start with a list of arrays, each of which has a (3,) shape.  Apparently you want each to have a (3,1) shape.  Why?  What's the benefit of that?  Just a prettier display, or is it necessary for further processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `np.expand_dims` for each element in the `data` list like this:

```
import numpy as np
data=[np.array(['one','two','three']),np.array(['four','five','six'])]
data = [np.expand_dims(ele, axis=1) for ele in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, @Tadhg proposed to take the transpose of each element. At first glance, that may seem to be correct. But, the transpose of a 1D-vector such as:

```
array(['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

is simply:

```
array(['one',
       'two',
       'three'])
```

Note that the vector has not really changed, it still has the same shape `(3,)`. To get the desired result, you would need to introduce another dimensions before transposing, e.g. like this: `array([['one', 'two', 'three']])`. The transpose of an array with a shape of `(1, 3)` would have a shape of `(3, 1)`, which is exactly what you want. All that is left is to apply that to each entry in your data matrix:

```
[np.array([a]).T for a in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[np.array_split(a,len(a)) for a in data]
```

Numpy has a default function called `array_split()` to split the list into number of lists that you want.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You are absolutely right. Added Explanation.