# matrix multiplication in a customized way

Tags: python, numpy

I have a array of the size `(3,)`:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
```

and another array of the size `(3,3)`:

```py
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I am looking for a vectorized way to multiply the `a**2` (a^2) to b in a way to:

```
> a**2=[1,4,9]
```

multiplies that 1 to entire row 1 from matrix b
4 to the second row of the matrix b
and 9 to the entire row of the matrix b.

my final result has to be this:

```
> (a**2)*b = [[1,2,3],[16,20,24],[63,72,81]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `np.einsum('i,i,ij->ij',a,a,b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first makes `a` (1D: (3, )) and `b` (2D: (3, 3)) the same in terms of dimensions. So, it is needed to add a dimension to `a`, which can be done by one of the following methods:

```
a = a[:, None]                    # way 1
a = a[:, np.newaxis]              # way 2
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)     # way 3
```

and then do your calculations on it as:

```
formula = a ** 2 * b
```

***Note:*** *as it is good explained in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755697/13394817)*, ***it is recommended to use way 2 or way 3 instead of way 1***.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert your arrays into `numpy` arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)
```

You can use:

```py
(a**2)[:, None] * b
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [16, 20, 24],
       [63, 72, 81]])
```

Comment: It worked :)
What [:, None] means? :)

Comment: @pedram Cool! In this case, it is just converting array of shape `(3,)` into `(3, 1)` which we need for cell to row multiplication