# Python - how to add another "column" to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a 34000,18 dimension numpy array and I have a 34000,1 array that needs to be appended to the first one at the end.

`X_train.shape`
=(34189, 18)

`type(X_train)`
= numpy.ndarray

`y_train.shape`
= (34189,)

my attempt:

Data = np.append(X_train,y_train)
and now its returning a (649591,) np array.

Any help please?

Additionally, how would I take a column out of the numpy.ndarray?
I.e after I have put them together and I have sorted my data- how would i then proceed to take the (34189,19) dimension array and turn it into two arrays being - (34189, 18) and (34189, 1)? (reversing what I am asking above)

Thank you

Comment: [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71533064/13394817)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array with `ndim == 1` is implicitly a row, not a column. The simplest way would be to turn it into a column and use `np.concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate((X_train, Y_train[:, None]), axis=1)
```

You could do the same with `np.append`:

```
np.append(X_train, Y_train[:, None], axis=1)
```

Other ways to turn `Y_train` into a column include `Y_train.reshape(-1, 1)` and `np.atleast_2d(Y_train)`.

Comment: Thank you for this! It has worked. Do you know how to separate the big ndarray into two separate ndarrays?

Comment: @noahm. Indexing of course