# Append child numpy arrays iteratively to another parent numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I have been facing this problem where I have several `numpy` arrays of `(10, 3)` dimensions, for example one of these could be:

```
array([[12.780001, 57.850002, 55.230003],
        [12.68    , 57.590004, 53.730003],
        [12.860001, 56.100002, 53.47    ],
        [14.16    , 55.590004, 54.090004],
        [14.200001, 55.98    , 55.58    ],
        [12.73    , 59.24    , 55.39    ],
        [11.41    , 57.93    , 53.21    ],
        [12.89    , 55.940002, 52.070004],
        [15.290001, 56.15    , 53.41    ],
        [14.000001, 57.380005, 55.730003]], dtype=float32)
```

and I want to add them all inside a parent array, with an extra first axis, i.e. `(X, 10, 3)` dimensions.
The point here is that I have to do so iteratively inside a `for` loop, so `numpy.stack()`, which I thought would work, does not because it keeps adding an extra dimension for each loop iteration.

The final array could look like this:

```
array([[[12.780001, 57.850002, 55.230003],
        [12.68    , 57.590004, 53.730003],
        [12.860001, 56.100002, 53.47    ],
        [14.16    , 55.590004, 54.090004],
        [14.200001, 55.98    , 55.58    ],
        [12.73    , 59.24    , 55.39    ],
        [11.41    , 57.93    , 53.21    ],
        [12.89    , 55.940002, 52.070004],
        [15.290001, 56.15    , 53.41    ],
        [14.000001, 57.380005, 55.730003]],

       [[14.02    , 57.72    , 55.32    ],
        [13.310001, 58.110004, 54.      ],
        [12.490001, 56.860004, 53.560005],
        [13.5     , 55.730003, 53.27    ],
        [14.370001, 55.49    , 54.53    ],
        [14.670001, 58.9     , 55.85    ],
        [12.43    , 59.25    , 54.14    ],
        [11.650001, 57.140003, 52.43    ],
        [14.320001, 56.100002, 52.170006],
        [14.950001, 56.720005, 55.010002]], 

       [[12.780001, 57.850002, 55.230003],
        [12.68    , 57.590004, 53.730003],
        [12.860001, 56.100002, 53.47    ],
        [14.16    , 55.590004, 54.090004],
        [14.200001, 55.98    , 55.58    ],
        [12.73    , 59.24    , 55.39    ],
        [11.41    , 57.93    , 53.21    ],
        [12.89    , 55.940002, 52.070004],
        [15.290001, 56.15    , 53.41    ],
        [14.000001, 57.380005, 55.730003]]], dtype=float32)
```

I have tried several approaches, different `numpy` functions (`concatenate`, `stack`, `vstack`), but none of them does what I need, either they flatten the array, or build a new stacked array but without that extra first axis which comprehends all the child arrays.

I ended up using the following workaround, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do this by means of a numpy function, which I guess it does.

Basically, I created a python list, i.e. `list_of_arr`, and then I added the child arrays into this list, and eventually when the `for` loop finishes I use `arr = numpy.array(list_of_arr)` to add that extra parent level.

Comment: *"I have to do so iteratively inside a for loop"* - can you post that loop?

Comment: That list work around is the right thing.  All those array methods return a new array each time and are less efficient.  And as you found trickier to get right.

Comment: All those `concatenate` based functions take a list of arrays as argument.  They are designed to handle more than two at a time.  Thus `stack` can can join the whole liat with one call.

Comment: You **should** use a list to iteratively append, that is the correct solution. You then use one of those numpy methods to create one big array from the arrays in the list

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the dimensions of the arrays before stacking them. That will give you an array as you are looking for.

Here you would convert each (10, 3) shaped array into a (1, 10, 3) shaped array. Stacking these with `vstack` will concatenate them along their first axis.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

arr = np.random.random((10, 3))
# Change shape of arr from (10, 3) to (1, 10, 3)
arrs = arr[np.newaxis, :] # <=> np.expand_dims(arrs, axis = 0)

for i in range(3):
    arr = np.random.random((10, 3)) # Or use shape (1, 10, 3) directly
    arr = arr[np.newaxis, :]
    arrs = np.vstack((arrs, arr)) # <=> np.concatenate([arrs, arr])

arrs
```

Output:

```py
array([[[0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338],
        [0.54488318, 0.4236548 , 0.64589411],
        [0.43758721, 0.891773  , 0.96366276],
        [0.38344152, 0.79172504, 0.52889492],
        [0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606],
        [0.0871293 , 0.0202184 , 0.83261985],
        [0.77815675, 0.87001215, 0.97861834],
        [0.79915856, 0.46147936, 0.78052918],
        [0.11827443, 0.63992102, 0.14335329],
        [0.94466892, 0.52184832, 0.41466194]],

       [[0.26455561, 0.77423369, 0.45615033],
        [0.56843395, 0.0187898 , 0.6176355 ],
        [0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808],
        [0.6818203 , 0.3595079 , 0.43703195],
        [0.6976312 , 0.06022547, 0.66676672],
        [0.67063787, 0.21038256, 0.1289263 ],
        [0.31542835, 0.36371077, 0.57019677],
        [0.43860151, 0.98837384, 0.10204481],
        [0.20887676, 0.16130952, 0.65310833],
        [0.2532916 , 0.46631077, 0.24442559]],

       [[0.15896958, 0.11037514, 0.65632959],
        [0.13818295, 0.19658236, 0.36872517],
        [0.82099323, 0.09710128, 0.83794491],
        [0.09609841, 0.97645947, 0.4686512 ],
        [0.97676109, 0.60484552, 0.73926358],
        [0.03918779, 0.28280696, 0.12019656],
        [0.2961402 , 0.11872772, 0.31798318],
        [0.41426299, 0.0641475 , 0.69247212],
        [0.56660145, 0.26538949, 0.52324805],
        [0.09394051, 0.5759465 , 0.9292962 ]]])
```

Also see [How can I add new dimensions to a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array) for expanding the dimensions of an array.

Comment: You should **not do this** this is a well known anti pattern

Comment: Totally agree. But as far as I understood that is exactly what @ricardlambea wanted to do.

Comment: If someone asks you, "how do I shoot myself in the foot to accomplish X?" You should probably say, "don't shoot yourself in the foot, do Y to accomplish X instead".